# Telethon: add contact by telegram ID

Tags: telegram, telethon

I can get a users unique telegram ID, for example by using `GetContactsRequest` or by `get_entity`. In some cases, I don't know a users unique telegram username or his phone number, but only this ID.
How can I use this ID to add a user to my contacts on a different account, that has never communicated with the associated user before?
When I try `get_entity` or `AddContactsRequest` with the previously obtained ID on a different account, I always get an error that this entity cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot simply add someone to your contacts list using their ID. You also needed a user_access_hash.

According to [Telethon's](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html) documentation:

> Entities’ ID are the same for all user and bot accounts, however, the
> access hash is different for each account, so trying to reuse the
> access hash from one account in another will not work.
>
> Sometimes, Telegram only needs to indicate the type of the entity
> along with their ID. For this purpose, Peer versions of the entities
> also exist, which just have the ID. You cannot get the hash out of
> them since you should not be needing it. The library probably has
> cached it before.
>
> Peers are enough to identify an entity, but they are not enough to
> make a request with them use them. You need to know their hash before
> you can “use them”, and to know the hash you need to “encounter” them,
> let it be in your dialogs, participants, message forwards, etc.
>
> Once the library has “seen” the entity, you can use their integer ID.
> You can’t use entities from IDs the library hasn’t seen. You must make
> the library see them at least once and disconnect properly. You know
> where the entities are and you must tell the library. It won’t guess
> for you.